# State from previous outlet with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-effect

I have simple setup with outlet and dynamic routes and on route change I want to fetch new data.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { Link, Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function OutletContainer() {
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState(null);

  let { outletComponentId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // keeps api response state from previous route.
    console.log(' ue inv id', apiResponse, outletComponentId);

    fetch(
      `https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/${outletComponentId}`
    ).then((r) => setApiResponse(r.url));

    return () => {
      console.log('runcleanup');
      setApiResponse(null);
    };
  }, [outletComponentId]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <nav style={{ borderRight: 'solid 1px', padding: '1rem' }}>
        {console.log('api', apiResponse, outletComponentId)}
        <Link key={13} to={`/outletContainer/${13}`}>
          13
        </Link>{' '}
        <Link key={12} to={`/outletContainer/${12}`}>
          12
        </Link>{' '}
        <Link key={2} to={`/outletContainer/${2}`}>
          2
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, the problem:
When i swtich from `/outletContainer/${12}` to `/outletContainer/${13}`
console.log in useEffect keeps the `apiResponse` value from route 12 in route 13, even thou  cleanup method in useEffect set `apiResponse` state null

```
  return () => {
      console.log('runcleanup');
      setApiResponse(null);
    };
```

My questions are:

1.Why is this happening? I was reading Dans blog post [about useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#tldr) but I got even more confused. Initial TLDR gave me hope, but down the road I got lost.
[image]

2.How to set state of a `apiResponse` to null each time i switch route.

You can check whole code on a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-agqlf5-f4f6gn?file=src/routes/outletContainer.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just an issue of misunderstanding Javascript closures. `apiResponse` is missing from the `useEffect` hook's dependency (*for good reason since including it would create a render loop*), so the code appears to be logging a stale state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // keeps api response state from previous route.
  console.log(' ue inv id', apiResponse, outletComponentId);

  fetch(
    `https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/${outletComponentId}`
  ).then((r) => setApiResponse(r.url));

  return () => {
    console.log('runcleanup');
    setApiResponse(null);
  };
}, [outletComponentId]);
```

You are also console logging in the render return as an unintentional side-effect. Other than these I don't see any real issue here with the state updates.

I suggest the following for accurate value logging. Move the extraneous logs into a separate `useEffect` hook to log when that value updates.

```
export default function OutletContainer() {
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState(null);

  const { outletComponentId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect', { outletComponentId }); // <-- log when outletComponentId changes

    if (outletComponentId) { // <-- only fetch, and update apiResponse, if outletComponentId
      fetch(
        `https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/${outletComponentId}`
      ).then((r) => {
        console.log("update apiResponse", r.url); // <-- enqueue state update
        setApiResponse(r.url);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      console.log('run cleanup');
      setApiResponse(null);
    };
  }, [outletComponentId]); // <-- outletComponentId is dependency

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('api updated', apiResponse); // <-- log when apiResponse changes
  }, [apiResponse]); // <-- apiResponse is dependency

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Rendered"); // <-- every render cycle
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <nav style={{ borderRight: 'solid 1px', padding: '1rem' }}>
        <Link key={13} to={`/outletContainer/${13}`}>
          13
        </Link>{' '}
        <Link key={12} to={`/outletContainer/${12}`}>
          12
        </Link>{' '}
        <Link key={2} to={`/outletContainer/${2}`}>
          2
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Produced Logs:

[image]

When outlet 13 is clicked the cleanup function runs and enqueues an `apiResponse` state update to null. Since the existing `apiResponse` state value is already null the update is ignored. The `useEffect` hook runs and updates the `apiResponse` state and there's the log from the second `useEffect` hook.

When outlet 12 is clicked the cleanup function runs and this time we see the update go through and log that the `apiResponse` was set back to null. We also see the fetch made and update the `apiResponse` to the new value.

Comment: what confuses me is that we have previous apiResponse state when useEffect gets triggered

`useEffect {outletComponentId: '13'} https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/12`
apiResponse respons is still /12 (previous component )

That is what confuses me, its like we have previous state -> cleanup -> than we can call for new fetch. 

Can you give me few more details?

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic Can you clarify what you are referring to, specifically? The state updates are occurring when I'd expect them to happen. Is the issue the console logs? These run in a different thread than the main JS thread your app is running in in the browser, so they might not necessarily agree to when they are called in effects by React code.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. 

So, when route is switched from route 'board/12' to 'board/13' state from apiResponse is kept from board/13 untill cleanup function clears it.

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic I think you are getting hung up on something. The `useEffect` cleanup function is run prior to the render cycle to clean up effects/etc from the previous render cycle. The `apiResponse` state update is enqueued and set to null on the subsequent render cycle. ***At the end*** of this subsequent render cycle the `useEffect` hook runs and makes another fetch and enqueues another `apiResponse` state update. I'll update answer with an additional logging so it's more overt what is happening and when.

Comment: Thank you. Figure it out. In my code I had extra dependency in dependency array